# Prove that $\left(\Re(x^*Bx)\right)^2+\left(\Im(x^*Bx)\right)^2\geq\left(\Re(x^*T^*ATx)\right)^2+\left(\Im(x^*T^*ATx)\right)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A=\mathrm{diag}\{e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\theta_2},e^{i\theta_3}\}$, $B=\mathrm{diag}\{\gamma e^{i\beta},0,\gamma e^{i\alpha}\}$, such that $\pi/2\geq\beta\geq\theta_j\geq\alpha\geq-\pi/2$ for $j=1,2,3$ and $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$, $\gamma>0$. Prove that
$$\left(\Re(x^*Bx)\right)^2+\left(\Im(x^*Bx)\right)^2\geq\left(\Re(x^*T^*ATx)\right)^2+\left(\Im(x^*T^*ATx)\right)^2$$

for any unit vector $x$ and any nonsingular $T$ such that $\sigma_{max}(T^*AT)\leq\gamma$. ($\sigma$ is singular value)

---

Lets $B=\gamma C$, where $C=\mathrm{diag}\{ e^{i\beta},0, e^{i\alpha}\}$

\begin{aligned}
\left(\Re(x^*Bx)\right)^2+\left(\Im(x^*Bx)\right)^2&\geq\left(\Re(x^*T^*ATx)\right)^2+\left(\Im(x^*T^*ATx)\right)^2\\
|x^\ast Bx|^2&\geq|x^\ast T^*ATx|^2\\
|x^\ast Bx|&\geq|x^\ast T^*ATx|\\
\gamma|x^\ast Cx|&\geq|x^\ast T^*ATx|\\
\end{aligned}

I am stuck from here.

Comment: Is it possible that you have the inequality backwards? I suspect that we have
$$\left(\Re(x^*Bx)\right)^2+\left(\Im(x^*Bx)\right)^2\geq\left(\Re(x^*T^*ATx)\right)^2+\left(\Im(x^*T^*ATx)\right)^2$$
under the given assumptions

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, thanks for correcting

Comment: It seems that something is still wrong with the problem. The result does not hold, for example, with 
$$
x =\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}. 
$$

Comment: Assuming the problem can be corrected, this result might be helpful: for any matrix $M$, we have $\|Mx\| \leq \sigma_{\max}(M) \|x\|$. With this and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$
|x^*T^*ATx| \leq \|x\| \cdot \|T^*ATx\| \leq \|x\| \cdot \sigma_{\max}(T^*AT) \cdot \|x\| = \sigma_{\max}(T^*AT) \cdot \|x\|^2.
$$